# How this syntax error can be solved in react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

[image]

I am using map function to get data from the array of objects. Also using react native elements for creating UI. Here is the code.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

import ProfileContent from "../components/ProfileContent";

class CallsScreen extends Component {

    const list = [
  {
    name: 'John Baker',
    avatar_url: require("../img/profile1.jpg"),
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui quaerendum definitionem cu.',
    icon: 'arrow-round-up',
    iconcolor: '#00c853'
  },

  {
    name: 'Samantha Stewart',
    avatar_url: require("../img/profile2.jpg"),
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui quaerendum definitionem cu.',
    icon: 'arrow-round-down',
    iconcolor: '#d50000'

  },

  {
    name: 'Lauren Murray',
    avatar_url: require("../img/profile3.jpg"),
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui quaerendum definitionem cu.',
    icon: 'arrow-round-up',
    iconcolor: '#00c853'
  },

  {
    name: 'Joel Henry',
    avatar_url: require("../img/profile4.jpg"),
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui quaerendum definitionem cu.',
    icon: 'arrow-round-down',
    iconcolor: '#00c853'
  },

]

  render() {
    return (

<List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>
  {
    list.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
        key={i}
        title={l.name}
        subtitle={l.subtitle}
        rightIcon={{ name: {l.icon}, style: { color: {l.iconcolor}}
      />


    ))
  }
</List>

  export default CallsScreen;
```

It shows syntax error on this line when I run the simulator. However, I don't know how to fix it.

```
rightIcon={{ name: {l.icon}, style: { color: {l.iconcolor}}
```

Can you help me to solve this syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra and missing parenthesis in your syntax

this

```
rightIcon={{ name: {l.icon}, style: { color: {l.iconcolor}}
```

should be this

```
rightIcon={{ name: l.icon, style: { color: l.iconcolor}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying it fixes that specific issue but now is showing this error. I've added an image in the above.

Comment: That related to `avatar` prop. When using local images with `require('...')` you need to pass it like `avatar={require('nameoftheimage.png')}`. giving an object with a `uri` prop is for remote images.